# How to utilize XDG directories and paths in Bash?

Tags: bash, directory-structure, freedesktop

I wonder how to access not only the variables defined in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` with `xdg-user-dir`, e.g. `"$(xdg-user-dir VIDEOS)"`, but also the following standard variables:

1. `XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache`
2. `XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config`
3. `XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share`
4. `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:-"/run/user/$USER"`
5. `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS:-/etc/xdg`
6. `XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share:/usr/share`

For that purpose I do the following in my `~/.bash_login` file:

```
# Define standard directories.
declare -gx XDG_CACHE_HOME=~/.cache
declare -gx XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/.config
declare -gx XDG_DATA_HOME=~/.local/share
declare -gx XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/$USER"
declare -gx XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="$(IFS=: path /etc/xdg)"
declare -gx XDG_DATA_DIRS="$(IFS=: path /usr/local/share:/usr/share)"
# Source supplementary directories to export or overwrite existing standard ones.
declare a="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/user-dirs.dirs"
if [[ -e $a ]]; then
  source "$a"
  declare b=""
  for b in ${!XDG_*}; do
    if [[ $b =~ ^XDG_[_[:alnum:]]+_DIR$ ]]; then
      declare -gx "$b"
    fi
  done
fi
```

Is there a mechanism to access the above directory and path variables other than the user directory variables defined by the "XDG" directory structure specification?

Comment: It's actually a number: `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR:-"/run/user/$UID"`

Answer (score 6):

Those environment variables are all optional. If they are not set then your script must substitute the default values given in [the specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) itself.

```
someprog --cachedir "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}"
```

Comment: This optionality is one of the main reasons why I define them once as environment variables because I don't want to repeat the default value upon every `"${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-~/.cache}"` access. Optimally there should exist a similar mechanism as there is with `"$(xdg-user-dir VIDEOS)"` providing that default value implicitly. That way I don't have to remember the default value for each and every XDG variable.

Comment: @Tim Friske: Note that `"${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-~/.cache}"` is incorrect, one should use `"${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}"` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `systemd-path` is widely available and it could be used to get paths with environment aware resolution and with proper fallbacks:

```bsh
$ systemd-path user-shared
/home/Xerkus/.local/share

$ HOME=/foo systemd-path user-shared
/foo/.local/share
$ XDG_DATA_HOME=/bar systemd-path user-shared
/bar
```

From man:

> systemd-path
> may be used to query system and user paths. The tool makes many of the paths described in file-hierarchy(7) queriable.
> When invoked without arguments a list of known paths and their current values is shown. ...

Answer (score 0):

Plus the defaults:

`man xdg-user-dir` => SEE ALSO: `xdg-user-dirs-update`(1)

`man xdg-user-dirs-update`=> SEE ALSO: `user-dirs.defaults`(5)

`man user-dirs.defaults` => `user-dirs.defaults` under first `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` (default: `/etc/xdg`)

So:

```
read -r -d : <<<"${XDG_CONFIG_DIRS:=/etc/xdg}" XDG_USER_DIRS_DEFAULTS
XDG_USER_DIRS_DEFAULTS+=/user-dirs.defaults
```