# Setting XDG_DATA_HOME and XDG_CONFIG_HOME on compile/per program

Tags: shell-script, software-installation, compiling, environment-variables

The goal is to have a `-dev` version and a stable repository-based version installed at the same time, but with different `data` and `config` directories so that the dev version is not operating on(and possibly corrupting) the stable version's data. They don't actually have to be able to *run* at the same time, although I wouldn't exactly complain about that extra feature.

I already know and use tools like `stow` or `checkinstall`, however as far as I can tell they're mostly for the installation part, not the actually running part.
I also know and use env vars like `XDG_DATA_HOME` and `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`([fd.org specs](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/ar01s03.html)) and - if the program actually uses them - they work pretty much exactly as I hoped they would.

However always creating wrappers that call the compiled version with e.g. `XDG_DATA_HOME=~/dev/<program>/data XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/dev/<program>/config` is kind of a nuisance. Plus, some of them then create their own GSettings/dconf folders so that I risk them getting out of sync with my global settings.

This time in particular it's about a feed reader called [Liferea](https://github.com/lwindolf/liferea) which stores its settings in `~/.config/liferea/` and its database in `~/.local/share/liferea`.
 Using   `XDG_*_HOME` prefixes works, but I'm looking more for something like `checkinstall`, some wrapper for `make install` maybe. Or possibly even some clever bash-fu that sets them if I'm calling a program from a certain directory or so. Like `directory == ~/dev/<prog>/ ? -> XDG_*_ ...`

I've already searched stackexchange and askubuntu, but all I could find was about keeping the binaries separated([[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57658/how-to-utilize-xdg-directories-and-paths-in-bash)
[[2]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126464/tools-to-manage-a-custom-installation-prefix-for-software-compiled-from-source)
[[3]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46656/effect-of-compiling-from-source-on-already-installed-applications)
[[4]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/keeping-track-of-programs)).